# Is there a way to use a variable without returning it with SPARQL "select *"?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, blank-nodes

Is there some way to use a kind of placeholder variable with SPARQL without returning it when using `SELECT *` ?

For example:

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
   ?s dcterms:title ?title; 
      foaf:person ?name. 
   ?s2 :inProject ?s. 
}
```

Where I would not want to return the `?s` variable, just the `?title`, `?name`, and `?s2` variables while leaving the `SELECT *`.

I understand I can limit the select results by using `SELECT ?title ?name ...`, but I'm just curious if there is some kind of notation for placeholder variables or some way to manage this.

---

### EDIT:

I understand you can use blank nodes to accomplish this in some cases, for example:

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
   _:s dcterms:title ?title; 
       foaf:person ?name. 
   ?s2 :inProject _:s. 
}
```

However, doesn't this cause problems since blank nodes can't be used across basic graph patterns?  For example, this breaks in the case:

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
   _:s dcterms:title ?title; 
       foaf:person ?name. 
   OPTIONAL { ?s2 :inProject _:s. }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of question at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/21173/use-a-variable-without-returning-it-with-select

Comment: "(kleene star)"  When you write `select * ...`, that's not a Kleene star.  The Kleene star means "zero or more repetitions of something".  E.g., `(ab)*` would match `"ababab"` and `"ab"` and `""`.  In `select *`, the `*` is just a run-of-the-mill wildcard.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor you are very correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For variables scoped to a single pattern yes, use the blank node variable syntax as you demonstrated in your question

In the general case no, if you use a variable then `SELECT *` will return it.

One possible workaround is to use sub-queries where you do list variables and leave out the variables you don't want e.g.

```
SELECT * WHERE
{ 
  {
    SELECT ?title ?name ?s2 WHERE 
    {
      ?s dcterms:title ?title; 
      foaf:person ?name. 
      OPTIONAL{ ?s2 :inProject ?s. }
    }
  }
}
```

But then I assume this is exactly what you are trying to avoid since you end up listing variables anyway.